# Click the submit button via javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, submit, form-submit

I am trying to automate the javascipt code by include the automatic submit code. i want to click the submit button using the java script. Can someone help?

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="MAN" id="man" onclick="/Authon/checks">MAN</a>`

I have tried the below few tries, but didnt work :(

`document.getElementById('man').click();`

`$("#man").trigger('click');`

Comment: What exactly do you expect `onclick="/Authon/checks"` to *do*?

Comment: If you have a form element, just trigger submit() on the form, instead of the A element.

Comment: You don't need to automate the `click` of the submit button. Just use `yourFormReference.submit()`.

Comment: And, don't use hyperlinks just because you want someone to click something. Just about any element supports a click event. Hyperlinks are for navigation, not to trigger click events.